partitionOverwriteMode dynamic and "logical" partitions
Can dynamic partitionOverwriteMode selectively overwrite parquet files that are not separated into Hive-style partitions (i.e. different directories)? Using row group filtering in parquet, it is possible to selectively ignore parquet files for I/O that could not possible contain data you are filtering on. I am wondering if partitionOverwriteMode dynamic can take advantage of similar optimization when selectively overwriting parquet files.
According to documentation, "When in dynamic partition overwrite mode, operations overwrite all existing data in each logical partition for which the write commits new data. Any existing logical partitions for which the write does not contain data remain unchanged."
https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/selective-overwrite.html#dynamic-partition-overwrites
However, I am not sure what logical partition means in this context
